# How can I detect black and white using an LED and a photodiode with an STM32?

Tags: microcontroller, led, circuit-design

I need to build a circuit that can distinguish white surface from black surface. Would it be doable if I place an LED (red) along with a photodiode next to it so when the circuit is pressed to the surface, it can trigger the LED and then measure the output of the photodiode?

The measuring distance would be less than 5 mm, so we can assume that the surface (in this case, paper - black or white) will cover the top of the LED and the photodiode next to it. Will this approach, including an LM358, work? I need to use it with a STM32F103.

Comment: Is the sensor in the dark (inside an enclosure, like in a printer) or exposed to ambient light?

Comment: your approach can work, if you don't have too much ambient light. If you do, consider switching the LED on and off rapidly, and comparing the photodiode response to cancel out the ambient light part. That is pretty much what the Lego Mindstorms light sensor does.

Comment: You can buy LEDs combined with Phototransistor sensors, like this: https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/qre1113-d.pdf  They usually use infrared light to minimize interference from external light. But, you still may need to modulate as Paul recommended.

Comment: Yes, your proposed approach using an LED, photodiode, LM358, and STM32F103 can work for distinguishing between a white and black surface. Make sure to consider ambient light conditions and possible interference factors during the calibration process.

Comment: The sensor will be inside an enclosure, with little exposure to ambient light. When the paper will be pressed against the sensor, it will further stop the ambient light from affecting. Is there any sample circuit someone can guide me to?

Comment: The answer by @Mattman944 is good; another sample circuit would be the Lego NXT light sensor which does the same thing with discrete transistors instead of an OpAmp. https://github.com/7Robot/RobAFIS/blob/master/2010/LEGO%20MINDSTORMS%20NXT%20Hardware%20Developer%20Kit/Appendix%203-LEGO%20MINDSTORMS%20NXT%20Light%20Sensor%20hardware%20schematic.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to use a comparator, or if your MCU has analog inputs, connect Q1 directly to the MCU.

But, the first step is to characterize your sensor. Build the left half and run some tests. See what voltage difference you can get with your black and white target. See how much interference you get from ambient light. Vary R1 and R2 if necessary.

Note that the LM339 needs to have at least one input below +V minus 2 volts. It is easy to avoid this issue in a simple circuit like this. Or, you can use a rail-to-rail comparator.

If the ambient light is too high, you will need to put an oscillator on the LED, AC-couple the transistor output, etc. That would be another question if necessary.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3I4nb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>